# Using a jQuery function with a PHP while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a website for a client, but I'm primarily a front-end developer. I had to create a while loop (which works just fine) to build a gallery. The client wants a before/after display on the gallery. I elected to use the [TwentyTwo](http://zurb.com/playground/twentytwenty) jQuery plugin. However, I am having an issue. It is only displaying the first container, which displays just fine.

The necessary jQuery, inline , and css files are displayed on that page linked above. I am using bootstrap as a framework. Here is my code:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#container1").twentytwenty();
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <h2><span class="color">Our Gallery</span> </h2>
    <?php
            //Selects all images
            $sql = $GLOBALS['gmysqli']->query("SELECT image FROM gallery ORDER BY postDate DESC") or die($GLOBALS['gmysqli']->error);
    
            while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
                $image = $row["image"];
                ?>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
        <div id="container1" class="twentytwenty-container">
          <img src="<?php echo $beforeimage; ?>">
          <img src="<?php echo $afterimage; ?>">
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are using a fixed ID within the loop, this will result in duplicate ID in your document. That's not valid. 
Other then that: How do you call the jQuery function? As it stands now the questions has nothing to do with jQuery itself but only with PHP and Mysql.
Does `$row` contain all images you expect it to do?

Comment: Yes, it will display all images if I were to structure it without this jQuery function. I call the jQuery function using the included script on that page. It's <script> $(window).load(function() { $("#container1").twentytwenty(); }); </script>

Is there some way that I could make the container ID different every time? On the example page they included, they used the same ID for every div with that image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the duplicate ID you generating in the php loop. This results in invalid html and can cause problems when using it as a selector.

You can switch to using a class selector:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".twentytwenty-container").twentytwenty();
});
```

I updated your `ready` handler to the recommend structure. Or for the shorthand:

```
$(function() {
    $(".twentytwenty-container").twentytwenty();
});
```

When using the class selector you can get rid of the ID in the HTML element
If you want to stick to the ID you can add a iteration variable to your loop and use the [attribute](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector:

```js
$(function() {
  $( "div[id^='container-']" ).twentytwenty();
});
```

```html
<?php
$i = 0; 
while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) { 
  $image = $row["image"]; ?>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
    <div id="container-<?php echo $i; ?>" class="twentytwenty-container">
      <img src="<?php echo $beforeimage; ?>">
      <img src="<?php echo $afterimage; ?>">
    </div>
  </div>
<?php 
  $i++;
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try without **order by** statement.

Example:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h2><span class="color">Our Gallery</span> </h2>
                    <?php
                            //Selects all images
                            $sql = $GLOBALS['gmysqli']->query("SELECT image FROM gallery") or die($GLOBALS['gmysqli']->error);

                            while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc())
                            { $image = $row["image"]; ?>                        
                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                                <div id="container1" class="twentytwenty-container">
                                <img src="<?php echo $beforeimage; ?>">
                                <img src="<?php echo $afterimage; ?>">
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

If you could share how you database are filled out could more easy to help you.

And the project link.

I hope helped you out anyway.